# Why does capturing the capture group identified with this regex search pattern fail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text_substring = "durante el transcurso del mes de diciembre de 2350" #example 1
#input_text_substring = "durante el transcurso del mes de diciembre del año 2350" #example 2
#input_text_substring = "durante el transcurso del mes 12 2350" #example 3

##If it is NOT "del año" + "(it doesn't matter how many digits)" or if it is NOT "(it doesn't matter what comes before it)" + "(year of 4 digits)"
if not re.search(r"(?:(?:del|de[\s|]*el|el)[\s|]*(?:año|ano)[\s|]*\d*|.*\d{4}$)", input_text_substring):
    input_text_substring += " de " + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y') + " "

#For when no previous phrase indicative of context was indicated, for example "del año" and the number of digits is not 4

some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*?\n)[^;])*" #a number of month or some other text without dots .  or ;, or \n ((although it must also admit the possible case where there is nothing in the middle or only a whitespace)

#we need to capture the group in the position of the last \d*
m1 = re.search( r"(?:del[\s|]*mes|de[\s|]*el[\s|]*mes|de[\s|]*mes|\d{2})" + some_text + r"(?P<year>\d*)" , str(input_text_substring), re.IGNORECASE, )
#if m1: identified_year = str(m1.groups()["\g<year>"])
if m1: identified_year = str(m1.groups()[0])

input_text_substring = re.sub( r"(?:del[\s|]*mes|de[\s|]*el[\s|]*mes|de[\s|]*mes|\d{2})" + some_text + r"\d*", identified_year, input_text_substring )


print(repr(identified_year))
print(repr(input_text_substring))
```

This is the wrong output that I get with this code (tested in the example 1):

```
''
'durante el transcurso '
```

And this is the correct output that I need:

```
'2350' #in example 1, 2 and 3
'durante el transcurso del mes de diciembre 2350' #in example 1 and 2
'durante el transcurso del mes 12 2350' #in example 3
```

Why can't I capture the numeric value of the years `(?P<year>\d*)` using the capture group references with `m1.groups()["\g<year>"]` or `m1.groups()[0]` ?

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect "del mes..." to be included in the final output, when in the last call of `re.sub` you explicitly match and remove that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<year>` part is not matched because the previous pattern is capturing that year with `[^;]` and a greedy `*`.

One way to have the previous pattern not consume the year, is to extend the negative look-ahead as follows:

```
some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*?\n|\d{4})[^;])*"
#                           ^^^^^^
```

In the expected results you want to keep "del mes..." in the final output of `input_text_substring`, but if that is the case then just don't remove that part of the string with the last call of `re.sub` -- remove that statement. But maybe you overlooked this in your question?

Finally, `[\s|]*` is not really what you want: it would match a literal `|` in your input. Moreover, you seem to want to match at *least one* white space character. So replace these occurrences with `\s+`.

Comment: Really thanks for the help!!, the pattern `some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*?\n|\d{4})[^;])*"` that you gave me worked perfect at the time of capturing the year. But I have been trying in various ways, but i always have the same problem, , and it is that the replacement of `""del mes "` is always done, and that should not be done. It's hard to figure out with re.sub() without replacing everything, and that's something I hadn't considered.